# VLC doesn't work properly on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vlc

I've installed vlc but when I try to open it no window pops up, only the icon shows up on the taskbar. Furthermore when I open video files there is only sound and no picture.

Comment: try to reinstall vlc by running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc`

Answer (score 6):

I was getting a similar (possibly the same) error: when running from the console:

```
$ vlc
VLC media player 2.1.2 Rincewind (revision 2.1.2-0-ga4c4876)
[0x25f4978] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x25af058] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x25af058] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
```

Running Avinash's command fixed things for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools→Preferences→Video
Remove the tick for Accelerated video output (Overlay)
Try and play the movie again, you should now see output.

Answer (score 0):

Go to vlc menu  > tool > preferences  > video  >   untick the accelerated video output(overlay)  > select x11 video output(xcb) in output option

now vlc will run smoothly.