# VLC loses sound in Ubuntu 14.04 after update playing ogg-files

Tags: 14.04, alsa, vlc

1. Updated to Ubuntu 13.10 Ubuntu 14.04 (by choosing to install over the current Ubuntu 13.10 DVD)
2. Installed VLC (not reset update script)
3. All the settings are saved (from 13.10)

BUT ...

When playing .ogg-files the sound suddenly disappears, although the slider continues to creep. While manipulating the slider the sound is restored.
In deriving window VLC-messages (the analogue of the log file) in mode 2 "debug" at the time of the termination of the sound appears only one line:

```
pulse debug: underflow
```

but the same line may appear at other times (when the sound is not lost)

```
That's like a piece of log
Normal playback ... ...
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
pulse debug: underflow
pulse debug: underflow
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Stream buffering done (352 ms in 0 ms)
main debug: End of audio preroll
main debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
pulse debug: underflow
pulse debug: underflow
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: Buffering 0%
main debug: End of audio preroll
main debug: Buffering 98%
main debug: Stream buffering done (631 ms in 0 ms)
main debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
pulse debug: underflow
.. Mute ...
pulse debug: underflow
```

Reset settings to default - did not help

In the previous 13.10 and 13.04 I didn't have this error.

Comment: i did try solve by http://askubuntu.com/questions/460620/vlc-doesnt-work-properly-on-ubuntu-14-04?rq=1 ( "reinstall vlc by running sudo apt-get install --reinstall vlc" ) , but also did not help